# Display pivot tables in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, pivot-table, spyder

In fact, as I am newbie to python, I have a lot and a lot of questions. Before I post a question here, I have searched a lot for the topic but couldn't find a clue.
I have such a line that creates a pivot table using `Pandas` package and the code works fine in Jupyter Notebook

```
df_bal.pivot_table(index='Grouping', values='Balance', aggfunc=sum)
```

But I am using Spyder IDE now and I would like to know if it is possible to view or display the pivot tables in spyder or not. All what I can do is to assign a variable to the DataFrame

```
x=df_bal.pivot_table(index='Grouping', values='Balance', aggfunc=sum)
```

and double-click in the `variable explorer` to see the contents .. But the view is not good as in Jupyter Notebbok

Answer (score 1):

To enable using Jupyter Notebook inside Spyder IDE go to this link for more details https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook

** First step is run Anaconda Prompt

** Activate the environment you are working on

```
conda activate myenv
```

** Install the Jupyter package if not installed

```
conda install jupyter
```

** Install the package from the link spyder-notebook

```
conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide
```

** Type `spyder` to launch Spyder IDE > Notice the bottom part has two sections `Editor` and `Notebook`. Right-Click inside `Notebook` section and open any file with the extension `ipynb`

** If the file opened appeared in blank then try to use this line in the console of spyder

```
conda install traitlets=4
```